# How does elasticsearch work?

Tags: elasticsearch

How does Elasticsearch handle indices? I have a field called `Coordinates` which has subfields `lat` and `lng` in a collection called `users`. I want to search inside this collection but by indexing the coordinate field. In my MongoDB configuration the `coordinate` field is already a 2D index. How can I try to tell ElasticSearch to search indexing that field? Does it know that coordinates is an index ? or should I tell it by this script?

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_river/artist/_meta" -d'
{
  "type": "mongodb",
    "mongodb": {
      "db": "mydb", 
      "collection": "users"
    },
    "index": {
      "name": "coordin", 
      "type": "coordinates"
    }
}'
```

Comment: I've made some edits however its still very unclear as to what you require. I suggest reading some articles as to how ElasticSearch works, watch some tutorials etc. Some articles here might help - http://blog.smeef.co.uk/category/elastic-search/

Comment: Also some very good articles located here - https://www.found.no/foundation/

Answer (score 1):

I assume that here by "index" you mean like the ones at MongoDB and SQL server. At [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/what-is-an-elasticsearch-index) context it is a collection of `types` and `documents`, more like a database is a collection of `tables` and `rows`. By default all fields in elasticsearch are stored into a [Lucene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene) data structure from which it can be efficiently be queried.

Elasticsearch does support indexed geospatial data, documentation can be found from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-shape-type.html).

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch works by your index configuration, assuming that you already configured everything and you are ready to receive some files you need to edit the file locate in `/etc/elasticsearch/templates/`
in my example below is a `log4net` and I added the geospatial configuration that I found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-geo-point-type.html):

```
{
  "log4net": {
    "template": "log4net*",
    "mappings": {
      "fluentd": {
        "_ttl": {
          "enabled": true,
          "default": "62d"
        },
        "properties": {
          "hostname": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "level": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "enviroment": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "site": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "username": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "logger": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "thread": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "systemname": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "location": {
            "type": "geo_point",
            "fielddata": {
              "format": "compressed",
              "precision": "1cm"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```